# About a passage from a published Chinese translation of Kafka's "The Trial"

Tags: translation, culture, history, books, literature

According to Bing-AI, Kafka's novel "The trial" (German: "Der Prozess") was translated many times into Chinese by different translators and in different times up to only recently in 2004.

This might be of course the imagination of the AI but even the German Amazon page lists a few translations to Chinese of this novel which are available for sale in Germany.

Anyways, if you have a copy of a Chinese published translation of this novel at hand, I am interested in the Chinese translation of a few sentences from the very last page, commenting on the execution of K. Every published translation is welcome with reference to the translator. I would like to gather as many translations as possible.

Here's the paragraph:

> Gab es Einwände, die man vergessen hatte? Gewiss gab es solche. Die Logik ist zwar unerschütterlich, aber einem Mensch, der leben will, widersteht sie nicht.

And further the very last sentence:

> "Wie ein Hund!", sagte er, es war, als sollte die Scham ihn überleben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[《审判》](https://www.kanunu8.com/book3/7591/165653.html)

This doesn't look like an excellent translation, but none the less here you go:

> 是不是以前被忽略的有利于他的论点又有人提出来了？当然，这样的论点应该有。逻辑无疑是不可动摇的，但它阻挡不了一个想活下去的人。

and

> “像一条狗似的！”他说；他的意思似乎是：他死了，但这种耻辱将留存人间。

Comment: 非常感谢，sorry if I bump for more questions. But who is the translator of the document in the link?

Comment: @ChristophMark I'm not really sure, but it seems to be all over the net. I'll dig a little more and see if I can see who translated it. There is a translation by 文泽尔. It's possible that it could be his. Unlikely though as that would be quite recent.